# Getting SearchWidget result to JavaScript variable?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, search, widget

I'm using the following searchWidget and it works fine, I need to know how can I get location details, once I type something and hit enter.
Lets I search for New York and hit enter, then search data should be taken into a variable (search value, location details, etc).

```
  var searchWidget = new Search({
        sources:[{
          countryCode:"LKR",
          placeholder: "Search",
        }],
        view: this.view,
        includeDefaultSources: false,
        container : document.createElement("div")
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect to the `search-complete` event from the search widget, if you wanna use all the results given by the search; or the `select-result`, if you wanna use only the selected result.

```
var searchWidget = new Search({...});

searchWidget.on("select-result", function(event) {
  console.log("The selected search result: ", event);
});
```

You can find more information about the object returned by the event in the [official documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search.html#event-select-result)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i wanted

Comment: @SharePointLearner then please mark the answer as correct ;)